# Time in Text - Java

Tags: java, time

I made a code that formats the typed time(numbers) into text. But the problem is  when it's for example 10:30 he text should be "halb elf uhr" and not "halb zehn uhr" (language is german). So I think the case must be increased but how can I do this. 
I tried it with case+1 but that diddn't work.

This is the code:

```
public class TimeAsText {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type Hour: ");
        int hours = In.readInt();
        System.out.println("Type minutes: ");
        int minutes = In.readInt();;

        if(hours <1 || hours >12) {
            System.out.println("*****");
            System.exit(0);

        }else if (minutes <0 || minutes >59) {
            System.out.println("****"); 
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            String hourNames = null;
            switch(hours) {
                case 1: hourNames = "ein";break;
                case 2: hourNames = "zwei";break;
                case 3: hourNames = "drei";break;
                case 4: hourNames = "vier";break;
                case 5: hourNames = "fuenf";break;
                case 6: hourNames = "sechs";break;
                case 7: hourNames = "sieben";break;
                case 8: hourNames = "acht";break;
                case 9: hourNames = "neun";break;
                case 10: hourNames = "zehn";break;
                case 11: hourNames = "elf";break;
                case 12: hourNames = "zwoelf";break;
                default: System.out.println("Type valid hour");
            }
            String minuteNames = null;
            switch(minutes) {
                case 0: minuteNames = "punkt";break;
                case 1: minuteNames = "eines";break;
                case 2: minuteNames = "zwei";break;
                case 3: minuteNames = "drei";break;
                case 4: minuteNames = "vier";break;
                case 5: minuteNames = "fuenf";break;
                case 6: minuteNames = "sechs";break;
                case 7: minuteNames = "sieben";break;
                case 8: minuteNames = "acht";break;
                case 9: minuteNames = "neun";break;
                case 10: minuteNames = "zehn";break;
                case 11: minuteNames = "elf";break;
                case 12: minuteNames = "zwoelf";break;
                case 13: minuteNames = "dreizehn";break;
                case 14: minuteNames = "vierzehn";break;
                case 15: minuteNames = "viertel nach";break;
                case 16: minuteNames = "sechzehn";break;
                case 17: minuteNames = "siebzehn";break;
                case 18: minuteNames = "achtzeh";break;
                case 19: minuteNames = "neunzehn";break;
                case 20: minuteNames = "zwanzig";break;
                case 21: minuteNames = "einundzwanzig";break;
                case 22: minuteNames = "zweiundzwanzig";break;
                case 23: minuteNames = "dreiundzwanzig";break;
                case 24: minuteNames = "vierundzwanzig";break;
                case 25: minuteNames = "fuenfundzwanzig";break;
                case 26: minuteNames = "sechsundzwanzig";break;
                case 27: minuteNames = "siebenundzwanzig";break;
                case 28: minuteNames = "achtundzwanzig";break;
                case 29: minuteNames = "neunundzwanzig";break;
                case 30: minuteNames = "halb";break;
                case 31: minuteNames = "einunddreißig";break;
                case 32: minuteNames = "zweiunddreißig";break;
                case 33: minuteNames = "dreiunddreißig";break;
                case 34: minuteNames = "vierunddreißig";break;
                case 35: minuteNames = "fuenfunddreißig";break;
                case 36: minuteNames = "sechsunddreißig";break;
                case 37: minuteNames = "siebenunddreißig";break;
                case 38: minuteNames = "achtunddreißig";break;
                case 39: minuteNames = "neununddreißig";break;
                case 40: minuteNames = "vierzig";break;
                case 41: minuteNames = "einundvierzig";break;
                case 42: minuteNames = "zweiundvierzig";break;
                case 43: minuteNames = "dreiundvierzig";break;
                case 44: minuteNames = "vierundvierzig";break;
                case 45: minuteNames = "dreiviertel";break;
                case 46: minuteNames = "sechsudvierzig";break;
                case 47: minuteNames = "siebenundvierzig";break;
                case 48: minuteNames = "achtundvierzig";break;
                case 49: minuteNames = "neunundvierzig";break;
                case 50: minuteNames = "fuenfzig";break;
                case 51: minuteNames = "einundfuenfzig";break;
                case 52: minuteNames = "zwweiundfuenfzig";break;
                case 53: minuteNames = "dreiundfuenfzig";break;
                case 54: minuteNames = "vierundfuenfzig";break;
                case 55: minuteNames = "fuenfundfuenfzig";break;
                case 56: minuteNames = "sechsundfuenfzig";break;
                case 57: minuteNames = "siebenundfuenfzig";break;
                case 58: minuteNames = "achttundfuenfzig";break;
                case 59: minuteNames = "neunundfuenfzig";break;
                default: minuteNames = "Type valid nummer";break;
            }
            if(minutes == 0) {
                System.out.println(minuteNames + " " + hourNames + " uhr");
            }else if(minutes == 15) {
                System.out.println(minuteNames + " " + hourNames + " uhr");
            }else if(minutes == 30) {
                System.out.println(minuteNames + " " + hourNames + " uhr");
            }else if (minutes == 45) {
                System.out.println(minuteNames + " " + hourNames + " uhr");
            }else {
                System.out.println(hourNames + " uhr " + minuteNames);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you have 4 if statements which literally do the same....

Comment: your 60 element long switch case hurts my programmer feelings. sure you dont want to write a method which builds these from the number input alone? it wouldn't be too difficult. you just catch your special cases (like 0, 15, 30, 45) and in the default block you call that method. would result in a way nicer code which would probably also be easier to maintain

Answer (score 3):

The problem is sometimes you want to use the name of hours+1.
It is easiest to tackle such problems using the abstraction of several methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Type Hour: ");
    int hours = In.readInt();
    System.out.println("Type minutes: ");
    int minutes = In.readInt();;
    if (hours < 1 || hours > 12) {
        System.out.println("*****");
        System.exit(0);

    } else if (minutes < 0 || minutes > 59) {
        System.out.println("****"); 
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.println("Zeit: " + zeit(hours, minutes));
}

static String zeit(int hours, int minutes) {
    if (minutes == 0) {
        return hourName(hours) + " Uhr");
    } else if (minutes == 15) {
        return "Viertel nach " + hourName(hour) + " Uhr"); // Quarter past
        // Ex-DDR:
        //return "Viertel " + hourName(1 + (hour % 12)) + " Uhr"):
    } else if (minutes == 30) {
        int nextHour = hours + 1;
        if (nextHour > 12) {
            nextHour = 1;
        }
        return "Halb " + hourName(nextHour) + " Uhr");
    } else if (minutes == 45) {
        int nextHour = hours + 1;
        if (nextHour > 12) {
            nextHour = 1;
        }
        return "Viertel vor " + hourName(nextHour) + " Uhr");
    } else {
        return hourName(hours) + " Uhr " + minuteName(minutes));
    }
}

static String hourName(int hours) {
    String hourNames = null;
    switch(hours) {
    case 1: hourNames = "ein";break;
    case 2: hourNames = "zwei";break;
    case 3: hourNames = "drei";break;
    case 4: hourNames = "vier";break;
    case 5: hourNames = "f\u00FCnf";break;
    case 6: hourNames = "sechs";break;
    case 7: hourNames = "sieben";break;
    case 8: hourNames = "acht";break;
    case 9: hourNames = "neun";break;
    case 10: hourNames = "zehn";break;
    case 11: hourNames = "elf";break;
    case 12: hourNames = "zw\u00F6lf";break;
    default: System.out.println("Type valid hour");
    }
    return hourNames;
}

static String minuteName(int minutes) {
    String minuteNames = null;
    switch(minutes) {
    case 0: minuteNames = "punkt";break;
    case 1: minuteNames = "eines";break;
    case 2: minuteNames = "zwei";break;
    case 3: minuteNames = "drei";break;
    case 4: minuteNames = "vier";break;
    case 5: minuteNames = "f\u00FCnf";break;
    case 6: minuteNames = "sechs";break;
    case 7: minuteNames = "sieben";break;
    case 8: minuteNames = "acht";break;
    case 9: minuteNames = "neun";break;
    case 10: minuteNames = "zehn";break;
    case 11: minuteNames = "elf";break;
    case 12: minuteNames = "zw\u00F6lf";break;
    case 13: minuteNames = "dreizehn";break;
    case 14: minuteNames = "vierzehn";break;
    case 15: minuteNames = "f\u00FCnfzehn";break;
    case 16: minuteNames = "sechzehn";break;
    case 17: minuteNames = "siebzehn";break;
    case 18: minuteNames = "achtzeh";break;
    case 19: minuteNames = "neunzehn";break;
    case 20: minuteNames = "zwanzig";break;
    case 21: minuteNames = "einundzwanzig";break;
    case 22: minuteNames = "zweiundzwanzig";break;
    case 23: minuteNames = "dreiundzwanzig";break;
    case 24: minuteNames = "vierundzwanzig";break;
    case 25: minuteNames = "f\u00FCnfundzwanzig";break;
    case 26: minuteNames = "sechsundzwanzig";break;
    case 27: minuteNames = "siebenundzwanzig";break;
    case 28: minuteNames = "achtundzwanzig";break;
    case 29: minuteNames = "neunundzwanzig";break;
    case 30: minuteNames = "halb";break;
    case 31: minuteNames = "einunddreißig";break;
    case 32: minuteNames = "zweiunddreißig";break;
    case 33: minuteNames = "dreiunddreißig";break;
    case 34: minuteNames = "vierunddreißig";break;
    case 35: minuteNames = "fuenfunddreißig";break;
    case 36: minuteNames = "sechsunddreißig";break;
    case 37: minuteNames = "siebenunddreißig";break;
    case 38: minuteNames = "achtunddreißig";break;
    case 39: minuteNames = "neununddreißig";break;
    case 40: minuteNames = "vierzig";break;
    case 41: minuteNames = "einundvierzig";break;
    case 42: minuteNames = "zweiundvierzig";break;
    case 43: minuteNames = "dreiundvierzig";break;
    case 44: minuteNames = "vierundvierzig";break;
    case 45: minuteNames = "dreiviertel";break;
    case 46: minuteNames = "sechsudvierzig";break;
    case 47: minuteNames = "siebenundvierzig";break;
    case 48: minuteNames = "achtundvierzig";break;
    case 49: minuteNames = "neunundvierzig";break;
    case 50: minuteNames = "fuenfzig";break;
    case 51: minuteNames = "einundfuenfzig";break;
    case 52: minuteNames = "zwweiundfuenfzig";break;
    case 53: minuteNames = "dreiundfuenfzig";break;
    case 54: minuteNames = "vierundfuenfzig";break;
    case 55: minuteNames = "fuenfundfuenfzig";break;
    case 56: minuteNames = "sechsundfuenfzig";break;
    case 57: minuteNames = "siebenundfuenfzig";break;
    case 58: minuteNames = "achttundfuenfzig";break;
    case 59: minuteNames = "neunundfuenfzig";break;
    default: minuteNames = "Type valid nummer";break;
    }
    return minuteNames;
}
```

If you already know the *modulo* operator `%`:

```
    int nextHour = 1 + (hours % 12);
```

Comment: solid solution. very minor thing though: you copied the posters `case 1: minuteNames = "eines";break;` which should be `"eins"`

Comment: @LonelyNeuron thanks for mentioning that. I did see it, but thought: I am not going to deliver perfection to what might be homework. There are still other things to improve too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
System.out.println("Type Hour: ");
int hours = In.readInt();
System.out.println("Type minutes: ");
int minutes = In.readInt();
if (minutes == 30)
{
   hours++;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about 12:30!  Presumably that's _halb ein uhr_, not _halb dreizehn uhr_...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do some Object Oriented programming. I would create an interface WordFormat with a method like

```
public String format(int hours, int minutes)
```

and a concrete class that hods your implementation.

then you can create other concrete class that translate in a different way following certain rules (if minutes are 30 then return  else null).

at the end a class that allows you a logic like: given the ordered WordFormat, try to apply the first, if it fails (return null in my example) apply the second and so on until your last, default format...

Comment: while creating such a class for each language seems sensible, i wouldn't create multiple of these for different cases. this is heavily over engineered for such a tiny problem. especially since none of the implemented objects would be reusable

Comment: Mi suggestion was to implement a set of ordered rules, applied in a given order. And you're right, it is definitely better if the translation is held separately from the rule, because you can reuse the same rules.